# Best solutions to hide angular2 component in production mode?

Tags: testing, angular, typescript, angular2-routing, production

I imagine to create a route for a "dev" component and lock this route in production mode but I don't have any idea to do this.

Someone can show me in the main lines how can I do that?

Thx

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards

Comment: Thx @GünterZöchbauer I will take a look of this topic!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `isDevMode()` function to test if you are in production mode.
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/isDevMode-function.html
You could also use a `guard` in the route to block in while in production mode.